# java.lang.StackOverflowError while processing a xml using xsl

Tags: xslt-1.0, xalan

I am converting one xml format to another xml format using a XSLT. While processing I am getting following error

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.apache.xpath.objects.XString.equals(XString.java:336)
at org.apache.xpath.objects.XString.equals(XString.java:337
```

When I looked for a solution, I found a [Patch for this error](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANJ-2347)

I do not know I can I apply this patch so that the error will go away.Is that an issue with Xalan.jar version?

Would someone please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be issue of xalan library.What you need to do is either download the latest version or source code of xalan and build all over again.Still the same issue exists, copy those  lines mentioned in the patch file in `WalkerFactory.java` and build jar file again.

Comment: Its worked when I took latest version of xalan.jar i.e. 2.7.1